# Very slow query on table with Blob column

Tags: mysql, performance, blob

I have a table with approximately 3500 rows.  This table contains a longblob column with an average blob size of 750kb.  My query performance really deteriorates when trying to filter on the primary key column.

`Select * from tblphotos`  yields a response in 1 second, returns 3500 rows
`Select * from tblphotos where ActLogId = 20992`   yields a response in 130 seconds, returns 6 rows.

I'm looking for any sort of rationale as to why this is so slow and how to make this quicker.  Moving from ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT to DYNAMIC improved performance about 30%.

```
CREATE TABLE `tblphotos` (
  `PhotoID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `ActLogID` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Order` smallint(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PhotoFile` longblob,
  `PhotoA` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Caption` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Entered` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tblphotos`
--

INSERT INTO `tblphotos` (`PhotoID`, `ActLogID`, `Order`, `PhotoFile`, `PhotoA`, `Caption`, `Entered`) VALUES
(1, 19264, 1, blobvalued, 'JPG', 'Nameplate', NULL);


ALTER TABLE `tblphotos`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`PhotoID`),
  ADD KEY `ActLogID` (`PhotoID`,`ActLogID`,`Order`,`PhotoA`,`Caption`,`Entered`,`PhotoFile`(20)) USING BTREE;


-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `tblphotos`
--
ALTER TABLE `tblphotos`
  MODIFY `PhotoID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3421;
```

Comment: `Select * from tblphotos where ActLogId = 20992` cant use indexing. This query `Select * from tblphotos where PhotoID > 0 AND ActLogId = 20992` can use the index `ActLogID` looks like you may what to read this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: ive tested that hypothesis and it yields the same result.  The production query specifies the columns.

Comment: You said that you are filtering on Primary Key, but `ActLogId` is not your PK. `PhotoID` is your PK. Does that explain it?

Answer (score 2):

You need an index *starting* with `ActLogId`.

The indexes with lots of columns are likely to be not very useful.  Recommend getting rid of them, and redesign the indexes.

"Prefix" indexing (`PhotoFile(20)`) is rarely useful.

Read [*this cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) for tips on creating the optimal index for a query.

`where PhotoID > 0 AND ActLogId = 20992` needs a composite `INDEX(ActLogId, PhotoID)`, in *that* order (`=` first).